# Can I connect two devices only with access point without router

Tags: router, access-point

I want to connect to the tplink security camera via on it's app on my tablet. Two devices have to be connected to the same network. I don't need an internet connection. In this case, do I have to use a router to do this pr just an access point is enough to make a local network?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are off-topic here, as are question about applications and host/server configurations. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Ah, sorry for this misunderstanding. Should I delete my answer from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An access point is sufficient. Some access point models do not allow client to client communication unless specifically allowed. You also need to assign IP addresses, unless you use APIPA.